# Exemplo e ilustração sobre relacionamentos redundantes (MER)

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, modelo-relacional, relacionamento, entidade-relacionamento

## Contexto

Considere a sentença abaixo:

> Afirma-se:
>
> > Relacionamentos que são resultado da combinação de outros relacionamentos, entre as mesmas entidades, são denominados: **relacionamentos redundantes**

## Dúvida

Seria possível imaginar um desenho mental dessa sentença? eu tentei e deu nisso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém consegue achar uma forma melhor de representar? ou um explicar com um algum exemplo?

## Como surgiu?

A dúvida surgiu após responder essa questão de prova

Fonte: Provas: FCC - 2012 - TRE-CE - Analista Judiciário - Análise de Sistemas Disciplina: Banco de Dados (TI) - Assuntos: MER (Modelo Entidade Relacionamento)

Comment: Posso sugerir tentar colocar um título mais significativo? Tem alguma informação nessa dúvida mais relevante do que apenas o fato de ela ser de concurso. Por exemplo, você poderia perguntar o que são "relacionamentos redundantes" e por como fonte da dúvida essa questão, então entraria nos objetivos secundários da pergunta que seria remover as demais opções como válidas

Comment: Julgo não ser suficiente saber apenas o conceito sobre relacionamentos redundantes para responder a questão, e coloquei a resposta direto para ficar mais fácil de alguém tentar justificar o gabarito. Fiquei sem saber qual título colocar, por isso ficou um pouco genérico, acha melhor mudar para " O que são relacionamentos redundantes ?"

Comment: Creio que possa ser útil esse título sim. Se através dele você conseguir enviesar de modo a responder todas as suas dúvidas, ele é válido. Mas não leve apenas minha voz como fator definitivo, estou querendo tornar ela mais atrativa, mas a sua necessidade em primeiro lugar. E em segundo lugar, nem todas as pessoas tem o meu senso estético, então talvez as minhas sugestões possam piorar a atratividade para os olhos das demais pessoas

Comment: @JonathasB.C., não tem uma representação gráfica para isso. A definição dada na questão do concurso é um tanto complexa e até diria confusa. Precisei ler várias vezes para entender. Deixei uma resposta com dois exemplos para ti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relacionamentos redundantes são aqueles desnecessários que não precisam existir para você conseguir chegar a uma informação. Analisando a definição com uma leitura diferente, temos que se chegarmos a um resultado através do relacionamento entre diversas entidades, não precisaríamos de um novo relacionamento para representa-lo (pois os outros relacionamentos já a definem).

Exemplo 1: [PROFESSOR] ministra [CURSO] e [ALUNO] faz [CURSO], o primeiro com cardinalidade 1-N (supondo um professor exclusivo para 1 curso) e o segundo com cardinalidade N-N. Com essa configuração, eu sei quem é o professor de qualquer aluno, sem precisar fazer um relacionamento redundante entre ALUNO e PROFESSOR para isso.

Exemplo 2: [image: MER para Controle de Álbuns de Música]

Nesse caso, por exemplo, eu teria um relacionamento redundante caso eu criasse um relacionamento entre ALBUM e AUTHOR somente para saber que autor faz parte de cada álbum. Eu já consigo isso navegando pelos outros relacionamentos ALBUM->TRACK->MUSIC->AUTHOR.

Comment: Excelente resposta, agradeço.

Comment: De nada @JonathasB.C.